# I've wiped my WiFi icons and don't know which file to restore

Tags: macos, file, themes

I've been playing around with theming OS X, and in changing my menu bar icons to be white (to contrast my now-black menu bar) I've overwritten the original icons (and forgot to back them up).

Can someone running OS 10.8.x please confirm that the file /System/Library/Private/Frameworks/CoreWLANKIT.framework is the one I need to restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, I've uploaded a copy of `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWLAN.framework` here:

http://depositfiles.com/files/4cg5rhv5t

You can test that file (or use your backup) if you want. As always, you might rather reinstall the system than trust a file on the internet - even if I uploaded the correct file and had no ill intentions, the file could change before you download it, so it's always safer to get a file from your backup set or the verified install media from Apple.